# How to expose Enum in Solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, events

If you create a contract with a function like:

```
contract MyContract {
  enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar }
  event ThingHappened(MyEnum indexed _e)
  function foo(MyEnum _e) {
    // Code, code code...
  }
}
```

Solidity compiles that `enum` variable type down an `int8` (unless the `enum` has more than 8 options, in which case it walks up the `int` type scale), but that simply changes the signature of the `foo` function to be:

```
function foo(int8 _e)
```

and the event to be:

```
event ThingHappened(int8 indexed _e)
```

I'm not seeing a spelling out in the generated ABI JSON somewhere that spells out which `int` value goes with which `enum` value (e.g. 0 = `Foo`, 1 = `Bar`, etc.).

How best should contracts handle accepting an `enum` as an argument, or having an `enum` in an `event`, to share with the world what those integer values map to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create some getters to return the string representations of your enum.

Example:

```
contract MyContract {
  enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar }

  event ThingHappened(string _e);

  function getMyEnumKeys() public constant returns (string, string) {
    return ("Foo", "Bar");
  }

  function getMyEnumKeyByValue (MyEnum myEnum) public constant returns (string) {
    if (MyEnum.Foo == myEnum) return "Foo";
    if (MyEnum.Bar == myEnum) return "Bar";
    return "";
  }

  function getMyEnumValueByKey (string myEnum) external constant returns (MyEnum) {
    if (sha3(myEnum) == sha3("Foo")) return MyEnum.Foo;
    if (sha3(myEnum) == sha3("Bar")) return MyEnum.Bar;
    revert();
  }

  function foo(string _e) {
    MyEnum myEnum = getMyEnumValueByKey(_e);
    // do something with myEnum
    ThingHappened(_e);
  }
}
```

However, I think the best solution would be to just have it in your public documentation that Foo is 0 and Bar is 1.

Comment: If I execute this contract, what value will I pass to `getMyEnumKeyByValue()`: `0` or `MyEnum.Foo`?

Answer (score 0):

Publish the source with the enum definition. That's enough for devs to determine the corresponding int (plus a reference in whatever docs you release).

ENS took that approach in the [source code](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/HashRegistrarSimplified.sol#L110) for auction status:

```
enum Mode { Open, Auction, Owned, Forbidden, Reveal, NotYetAvailable }
...
function state(bytes32 _hash) constant returns (Mode) {
```

They provide more explanation in the [docs](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#starting-an-auction):

> This will return a single integer between 0 and 5. The full solidity data structure for this can be viewed here in the Registrar contract. The numbers represent different ‘states’ a name is currently in.
>
> - 0 - Name is available and the auction hasn’t started
> - 1 - Name is available and the auction has been started
> - 2 - Name is taken and currently owned by someone
> - 3 - Name is forbidden
> - 4 - Name is currently in the ‘reveal’ stage of the auction
> - 5 - Name is not yet available due to the ‘soft launch’ of names.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way. Let's say you have contract A and want to use his enum in contract B. Here's how:

```
contract A {
   enum MyItems { Example, NewOne }
}

contract B {
   function getItems() public {
      // Here the enum will be available with A.MyItems
      A.Myitems;
   }
}
```

Essentially you can access an enum by using the `ContractName.EnumName` when they are in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

```
      enum MyEnum {emty, blue, red }
      function getBackground(uint8 enumid)
        public
        pure
        returns (string memory)
    {
        string[4] memory backgrounds = [
            "", // Index 0 is empty
            "#141D48", // Dark Blue
            "#6F2430", // Dark Red
            "#6F2430"  // Pastel Brown
           
        ];

        return backgrounds[enumid];
    }
```